# How to get kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait to work

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

I cannot get kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait to work.

Expected:
On iPhone 6 Plus, the width of a banner should be 414 points.
On iPhone 6, the width of a banner should be 375 points.
On other iPhones and iPods ad this point, the banner would be 320 points.

Actual outcome:
I see the "320x50 Test Banner" on all devices. On wide devices, the 320x50 banner is centered in the view. The remaining space to the left and to the right has a grayish pattern.

Actual code used:

```
GADBannerView* newbanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
NSLog(@"newbanner size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newbanner.frame.size));
newbanner.adUnitID = @"/6499/example/banner";
newbanner.rootViewController = self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[
                        @"somedeviceid1",
                        @"somedeviceid2",
                        ];
[newbanner loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:newbanner];
newbanner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.5);
```

iPhone 6 Plus screenshot:

[image: iPhone 6 Plus screenshot of admob incorrectly sized smart banner ad.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait` only works on Android (and even there it's not perfect) for iOS I used `kGADAdSizeBanner` and in the control panel when providing a "Creative" (a.k.a image) for the ad make sure to also add retina version of the ad with 2x density.

[image]

Comment: I tried DFP (with no better results) too but am not really sure what the difference is between DFP and GAD requests. I found the documentation to be kind of hush-hush about that. I am not using the control panel yet, just the test banners for testing this technology. Are you saying real banners should work? Btw as a supplier of ad space, I assume I am not responsible for supplying the ad contents (the creatives etc). I assume that stuff comes from the ad network.

Comment: sorry i didn't properly read your code. See my edited answer. The test ad should work on all devices.

Comment: I'll wait a little more but as you say, it doesn't work on iOS as advertised. So that would be the "correct" answer. Yeah, I'll wait a little more in the event someone from say Google would chime in and explain.